# Заполнение полей неизменной информацией при многократном использовании приложения

Tags: android

Есть такой вопрос (не судите строго - новичок).

Пользователь ввёл некоторые данные в одном Activity, после закрыл приложение. Данные эти теперь должны быть ассоциированы с ним и только с ним, при этом при очередном заходе в приложение и переходе в тот самый Activity ранее введённые данные должны уже быть "захардкоженными" в полях (другими словами, их нет никакой возможности изменить). Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как этого добиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После того, как пользователь ввел данные - вы сохраняете их в БД (по клику на кнопку, либо при сворачивании окна). Данные храните локально, если не предусмотрен сервер. Когда пользователь снова заходит в то activity, вы выполняете запрос в базу. Проверяете есть ли уже такая запись? Если есть, то редактирование выключаете, поля заполняете. Если в вашем приложение предусмотрено, что пользователей на телефоне может быть более 1, то прежде вам нужно реализовать регистрацию. Думаю как-то так...

Comment: А аналогичное ведь можно проделать, используя Preferences? Просто ещё не работал с SQL в связке с android.

Comment: да, можно. Good practice in android are any libraries: realm, room. Not a SQL